# Create a new ROS Android package

Tags: rosmake, android, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow this tutorial "http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20ROS%20Android%20project"
in the end when I did
rosmake new_package
it shows "
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['new_package']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/luwei/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120422-221856
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['new_package'] to:
['new_package']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages new_package.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> new_package [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< new_package [SKIP] No rule to make target None
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/luwei/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120422-221856 "
Nothing created in the folder.
Does anyone know why?
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32362/create-a-new-ros-android-package/) by [luwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/2228/luwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the documentation here:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-android-application

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1